# Geo Fencing Intent Service not executing even once

Tags: android

I am implementing the example of Geo Fence. I have made a demo of it and I added the Geo Fence required latitude/longitude and radius but issue is that `IntentService` is not executing that give a whether it is enter/exit transition type.

**Question 1**: Why does it not executing once, any error which I could not catch?

**Question 2**: Does this Geo Fencing require to GPS Satellite and Use Wireless Network On?

**Question 3**: Does it require to have internet in your device to work this correctly?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener {

    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    private String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
            locationClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        ArrayList<Store> storeList = getStoreList();
        if (null != storeList && storeList.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Geofence> geofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
            for (Store store : storeList) {
                float radius = (float) store.radius;
                Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                        .setRequestId(store.id)
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                        .setCircularRegion(store.latitude, store.longitude, radius)
                        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                        .build();

                geofenceList.add(geofence);
            }

            PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, GeofenceIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            locationClient.addGeofences(geofenceList, geoFencePendingIntent, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected !");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddGeofencesResult(int i, String[] strings) {
        if (LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS == i) {
            //todo check geofence status
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, connectionResult.getErrorCode() + "");
    }

    private ArrayList<Store> getStoreList() {
        ArrayList<Store> storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Store store = new Store();
            store.id = String.valueOf(i);
            store.address = "India";
            store.latitude = 26.7802187;
            store.longitude = 75.860322;
            store.radius = 1.0;

            storeList.add(store);
        }

        return storeList;
    }

    public class Store {
        String id;
        String address;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        double radius;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != locationClient) {
            locationClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

GeofenceIntentService.java

```
public class GeofenceIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE = "ReceiveTransitionsIntentService";

    public GeofenceIntentService() {
        super(TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
            //todo error process
        } else {
            int transitionType = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
            if (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                    transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                List<Geofence> triggerList = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);

                for (Geofence geofence : triggerList) {
                    generateNotification(geofence.getRequestId(), "address you defined");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void generateNotification(String locationId, String address) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("id", locationId);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("address", address);
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dac_logo)
                        .setContentTitle(locationId)
                        .setContentText(address)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setWhen(when);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify((int) when, builder.build());
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/dac_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".GeofenceIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver android:name="com.location.demo.receivers.BootCompleteReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found an answers of two questions

> Does this Geo Fencing require to GPS Satellite and Use Wireless Network On?

Fused location provider, this is all manage by Google Play Service.

> Does it require to have internet in your device to work this correctly?

No, it does not require internet connection.

Comment: will it work,without internet and when app is killed